# Custom Android Rating Bar stretching image

Tags: android, layout, rating, ratingbar

I'm having a little problem when using a custom rating bar style. I've read other topics on this, but the proposed solutions/answers are not solving the problem.

Android seems to be stretching part of the star image, creating this strange effect: [image: bleeding]

This strange effect is even visible in the graphical layout preview tool in eclipse: [image: bleeding2]

The star "sprites" are: [image: empty star] and [image: full star]

This is the custom style:

```
<style name="ratingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/ratingBarHeight</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/ratingBarHeight</item>
</style>
```

And this is the xml code in the layout:

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/ratingBarHeight"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    style="@style/ratingBar" />
```

The height is defined as follows:

```
<dimen name="ratingBarHeight">32dip</dimen>
```

Comment: Kindly refer this link for your reference it will help you http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-custom-ratingbar-example.html

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The reason was that my drawable was smaller than `@dimen/ratingBarHeight`, it was 22 pixels. Changing `@dimen/ratingBarHeight` to `22dip` fixed it for me, the strange effect disappeared.

Comment: it doesn't work for every mobile screen.. so fixed height is not the proper solution!